# Adding primary key to Create [params] as query statement

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

How do you add a primary key to a create as query statement? I tried the following but it throws an error.  When I take out the primary key part, this query works without error:

```
  --redshift statement
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS egtable;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE egtable
  primary key (id),sortkey (b)
  as
  select 1 as id, 2 as b;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS egtable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE egtable
(
  id int,
  b int,
  primary key (id)  
)
distkey(b);

insert into egtable select 1, 2
```